# How can I change VS Code Remote Server's default download folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I often download file from vscode remote server, but how could I change default download folder? It always opens a specific folder I don't want to download into.

[image]
[image]

Comment: maybe add a feature request at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues for a new setting: `Download folder`

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4712

Comment: I opened a duplicate issue as it seems it didn't get enough votes in time... https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/5998

Comment: This problem discussion has been concentrated in this issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/140358

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about configuring the detault download directory, but there was an issue created and resolved to get VS Code to [Remember target directory when downloading files #140358](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/140358), which was implemented in commit [`ca936dc`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/ca936dcc94fba1f8d6c6de2b5984827571e24eaa).

[`bpasero`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/140358#issuecomment-1114574536) (one of the VS Code maintainers) [commented to close that issue as resolved](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/140358#issuecomment-1114574536):

> For the "Download" command we now remember the path where to download and restore that. This information is stored globally (i.e. applies to all windows) but will not roam via settings sync, because paths are typically machine local.
>
> Previously we did a questionable computation of a default path that typically always ended up in the user home directory, which imho does not make a lot of sense for the download operation.
>
> **Verification**:
>
> - connect desktop to any remote
> - right click from the explorer "Download"
> - pick a destination
> - repeat and verify the destination restores even across restarts